# How to grab the first url from a list urls and copy to clipboard in automator

Tags: applescript, automator

I am trying to setup an automator workflow. It gets to the point where automator extracts two URLS from the clipboard text and i can see them listed one after the other in the results window -  Great  - now i just want to copy the first url that it returns to the clipboard -

```
http://www.amazon
http://www.imageurl
```

would i use apple script? I can't find the answer anywhere .. please be explicit in your response i am only one hour into automation and apple scripting.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    return first paragraph of (input as text)
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set the clipboard to first item of input
end run
```

Greetings, Michael / Hamburg